# Nested list comprehension not the same as nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have the following nested loop:

```
for i in range(1,5): 
        for j in range(0,i):
                j
```

I get strange results when I try to re-express the same using the list comprehension

```
[j for j in range(0,i) for i in range(1,5)]
```

Firstly, can someone explain the output with this list comprehension? I can't really seem to understand what Python is doing here.

Secondly, can the inner `for`'s iterator not explicitly depend on the outer index?

Thirdly, is there any way to modify the list comprehension to get the same result as the nested for loop written at the beginning?

Comment: Swap the order of your loops in the list comprehension.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension doesn't do anything as it does not run without `i` already been defined outside the list comprehension.

To achieve what you want (and yes, this is counter intuitive ) you need to do this:

```
[j  for i in range(1,5) for j in range(0,i)]
```

This will yield:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

which is the same order as your nested for loops.

Comment: It does *compile*

Comment: not if i is not defined already.

Comment: What? Again, *it does compile*, or else it wouldn't raise a *runtime error*.

Comment: Ok, it raise a NameError.  Thanks for splitting the hair.

Comment: This is *programming*, it's all about splitting hairs.

Comment: That helps with fixing up the list comprehension expression. Could you explain why my original expression gave the output it did? How does Python know what `i` is if it is not defined?

Comment: I am guessing you already had another for loop above defining i, or had run something in the same console using i.  If you start a new python console and run your code you will se that python cannot run your original list comprehension.

Comment: @ChristianSloper That makes perfect sense, thank you. I'd already run quite a few things in my console before I came across this problem. I just executed the same expression in a fresh console instance, and indeed, it gave a NameError.